# two side by side DIV tags with same height

Tags: html, css

i am working on an internal web page, the page have a wrapper DIV as recommended by a tutorial online.
inside the wrapper there is : header, mainnav, content, sidenav and footer.
The content and sidenav are two side by side DIVs . 
The side bar contain a menu that is usually changed. 
My problem is that i want to make the content DIV with the same height as the sidenav.

here is my CSS for the two DIVs

```
#content {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}
#sidenav {
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
}
```

and this is the CSS for the wrapper

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 740px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px #999999;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px #999999;
}
```

Comment: See if it helps.. http://jsfiddle.net/kaAjW/3491/

Comment: Please post your HTML as well or we're unlikely to be able to help.

Comment: This is a duplicate of _so_ many questions, use the search.

Comment: sorry this is my firt post and i didnt know how it happenned

Answer (score 0):

height 100% doesnt work if you dont have a parent with a defined height. I dont know why you want the same height? If it is for a background color just add it to your wrapper and overwrite the sidebar for example.
In the future you might want to checkout a framework to overcome problems like this. bootstrap is a good one to start with.

https://jsfiddle.net/dtz8cmnt/1/

```
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.menu {
    background:red;
}
.content {
    background:blue;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In the Fiddle you find an example where a clear is used. Note that the colums do not have the same height.

Comment: Some designs call for various items of the same height to be side-by-side - that's his requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Give both of them the following attribute:

```
height:100%;
```

They should fill the entire height of the wrapper div, if you give it a specific height. I'd also suggest adding another div after them, and then style it as below to prevent either from creeping past it:

```
width: 100%;
clear: both;
```